# Top NAV not showing in Magento

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, magento-1.9

I installed fresh Magento Community Version 1.9.2.1 to my localhost. I added new category (Beverages) and then Added a new product (PEPSI). I assigned Pepsi to beverages but at my front end, top nav is not showing. I'm new to magento. Can anyone help me out? I'll be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure with the following things

1. Is Active = yes
2. Include in Navigation = yes
3. It must be sub category of Default Category otherwise you would not able see it
4. clear magento cache

let me know if you still facing any problem

Thanks

Comment: I made it sub category of Default Category and it was successfully displayed. Thankyou. How can I also add a static home page link to my nav bar? Can you help me with that too?

Comment: Okay you have to use "URL Rewrite Management" concept of magento in order to achieve this.

Comment: the following url help you to figure out the issue.http://www.pierluigipapeschi.com/index.php/en/11-magento/9-magento-url-rewrite-management

Answer (score 0):

Check in Category `Is Active` option set to `Yes` and `Include in Navigation Menu`  option set to `Yes`

Comment: Both are set to "Yes"

Comment: have you made any customization ?

Comment: No not yet. Just playing with admin panel.